# DateTime List find last date that before current

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have a list of dates:

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>
        {
            new DateTime(2016, 01, 01),
            new DateTime(2016, 02, 01),
            new DateTime(2016, 03, 01),
            new DateTime(2016, 04, 01),
            new DateTime(2016, 05, 01)
        };
```

Now given a certain date, a "StartDate". What is the easiest way to create a list of dates after the startdate, and the last date before?

I.E. - If I supply the date DateTime(2016, 03, 15), I need to return

```
DateTime(2016, 03, 01),
DateTime(2016, 04, 01),
DateTime(2016, 05, 01)
```

It could be as simple as finding the last "Active" date and then just using the where from that date. But I'm unsure on how to do this without making it really complicated.

Comment: Why would the first two not be present? All of your dates are after the start date... your example is very unclear.

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you mean? I have a list of dates from January to May. And my start date is the 15th of March? So I want to only return March, April and May.

Comment: Like `dates.Where(d => d > startDate).Union(dates.Max(d => d < startDate)); // ignores time` ?

Comment: put the startDate on the list, sort it, get the index of startDate done!

Comment: Doh, sorry - I see now.

Comment: @stuartd: Except you'd need one of those to be `>=` or `<=` to avoid missing a date which is exactly the same as what you're missing.

Comment: Just to check: is your list already sorted?

Comment: Yes my list is sorted.

Comment: @JonSkeet possibly, the requirements aren't completely clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making it complicated and if i understand your  requirements correctly. You want all the dates after the *StartDate* and the last entry before the first matching (**If Any**). Then I find this the easiest most readable way of doing it:

```
var results = dates.FindAll(x => x >= StartDate);
int index = dates.FindLastIndex(x => x < StartDate);

// there might be no match, if all the list is resulted
if (index >= 0)
    results.Insert(0, dates[index]);
```

If you prefer one query style, you can do the below (I find it not readable):

```
var results = dates.Where(x => x >= StartDate)
                   .Concat(dates.Where(x => x < StartDate)
                                 .OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(1));
```

Last Alternative if you like fancy ways:

```
int startIndex = dates.FindLastIndex(x=> x < StartDate);
startIndex = Math.Max(0, startIndex);

var results = dates.Skip(startIndex).ToList();
```

Comment: I wound up using this method :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If your list is already sorted, you can use a binary search:

```
var index = dates.BinarySearch(start);
// If the precise value isn't found, index will be the bitwise complement
// of the first index *later* than the target, so we need to subtract 1.
// But if there were no values earlier, we should start from 0.
if (index < 0)
{
    index = Math.Max(~index - 1, 0);
}
return dates.Skip(index).ToList();
```

This assumes the dates are unique. If there are multiple dates the same as `start`, there's no guarantee that it will find the first one. If that's a concern, you'd need to search backwards until you found the first match.

You haven't specified whether if there's an exact match, you want to include the date before that or not. If you do, you'll need to adjust this code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
var partialResult = dates.Where(x => x >= date).ToList();
partialResult.Add(dates.Where(x => x < date).Max());
IList<DateTime> result = partialResult.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```